# Why the base class's constructor method is called twice?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can anyone please tell me why the base class's constructor method is called twice?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    A(){
        cout << "default constructor of base class" << endl;
    }
};

class B:public A{
    public:
    B(){
        A();
        cout << "default constructor of derived class" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting this unexpected result:

```
default constructor of base class
default constructor of base class
default constructor of derived class
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once constructing the base sub-object of the `B` object in `main`:

```
B b;
```

Once constructing the temporary `A` object in the constructor of `B`:

```
A();
```

Perhaps you meant to initialise the `A` sub-object; do that in the initialiser list, not the constructor body:

```
B() : A() {
    cout << "default constructor of derived class" << endl;
}
```

although, in this case, that would do exactly the same thing as leaving it out altogether.

Answer (score 9):

The base-class constructor is called twice, because you create a temporary object of base-class in the derived-class ctor.

You might want to read about the ctor-init-list.

Answer (score 3):

This would involve two calls to base's constructor.

```
1) In the derived initializer list.
2) Your explicit call.
```

That is every member is constructed in the initializer list. If you won't provide any specific constructor then default constructor is used.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling A() inside B directly. However, in inheritance, when the default constructor is not overridden, the constructor of the Base class is called at first.

So, just remove A() within B's constructor as class A is the Base, it's constructor will be called first.